# ERB engine doesn't working with css link using rack gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, erb, rack

trying to serve files using rack gem and erb, the css link tag in html files erb is rendering doesn't seens to work:

[image]

helper used to execute erb and render view:

```
def render(file, *args)
    template = File.read("public/#{file}.html.erb") || 
    File.read("public/404.html.erb")
    template_output = ERB.new(template).result(binding)

    res = Rack::Response.new(bind_layout { template_output })
end

def bind_layout(&block)
    layout = File.read("public/layout.html.erb")
    ERB.new(layout).result(binding)
end
```

layout with css import:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/layout.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="main">
        <h1>ONM LAYOUT</h1>
        <%= yield %>
        <h2>onfoototer</h2>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

the page serves the templates and layout correctly, what isn't true for the linked css

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers or translation tools. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or easily copied and edited to create a solution.**

Comment: Is this Rails with the [Asset Pipeline](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) involved?

Comment: ty for feedback, just updated the images by the code, and no, i'm not using rails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was that rack was interpreting the file as html, serving all together with the binded html views. The solution I found was use Rack::Static to proper serve the static css as it should: `use Rack::Static, :urls => ['/static/stylesheets', 'layout.css']`.